# Delete Title Bar

Tags: homepage

I am new in WordPress and web development. Starting to learn. 
I have browsed through this site but couldn't find any way to solve my problem.

[image]

This is my homepage on the website that currently I'm building. I want to delete this brick picture. I tried to install a hide title plugin, but still unsuccessful.

This website link is nurulsazlinprubsntakaful.com.

Hope someone can help me.

Appreciate a lot.

tq

Comment: What theme are you using?  You should provide as much detail as possible when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the admin.  Click on Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS and paste in the following CSS.

```
.home .page_header {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This will hide the entire header area.  You could remove the image and add a color by adding something like this.

```
.home .page_header {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Note: the .home before each selector will only apply these to the homepage, because the body on the homepage has class .home.  If you want to apply these on all pages just remove the .home, like this...

```
.page_header {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: vesta theme. 

ur code solve this problem.tq

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your problem will be fixed by looking in the theme code, but since you are a novice of WP, the easiest way is to set the CSS property to hide it.

```
.page_header{display:none;}
```

you can put in at the end of file `style.css`

or

you can try the below code and put in at the end of file `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_hook_css');
function custom_hook_css() {
    if(is_home() && is_front_page()){
        echo '
            <style>
                .page_header {
                    display : none;
                }
            </style>
        ';
    }
}
```